# Problemas al firmar XML con C#

Tags: c#, .net

tengo el siguiente código para firmar XML:

```
    private XmlDocument FirmarXML(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string nombreCert)
    {
        X509Certificate2 myCert = new X509Certificate2();
        myCert = GetCertificateBySubject(nombreCert);

        var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24 /* PROV_RSA_AES */));

        key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;

        CspKeyContainerInfo keyInfo = key.CspKeyContainerInfo;

        var exportedKeyMaterial = myCert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(/* includePrivateParameters = */ true);

        key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

        SignXml(xmlDoc, key, myCert);

        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

Funciona a la perfección, pero esto solo funciona con certificados que sean exportables, no con certificados que no sean exportables´, y ahora necesito hacer que funcione con certificados que no tengan la llave privada como exportable, comente las lineas:

```
        var exportedKeyMaterial = myCert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(/* includePrivateParameters = */ true);

        key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);
```

y firma el XML pero ya no puedo verificar la firma, bueno creo que la pregunta del millon seria:

¿Como firmar un XML con un certificado con llave privada que no es exportable, este certificado no es un archivo fisico .pfx, est certificado se encuentra en el repositorio MMC?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el certificado que se encuentren instalados en el equipo local, se debe acceder por medio de un *store*:

```
public X509Certificate2 GetCertificateBySubjectName(string subjectName)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    var collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, subjectName, true /* Solo certificados válidos */);

    if (collection.Count > 0)
    {
        certificate = collection[0];
    }

    store.Close();

    return certificate;
}
```

Con esto buscará el certificado especificado por medio del *SubjectName*.
Si deseas buscar en otros *stores*, puedes cambiar las enumeraciones en el constructor:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

Esto dependerá del *store* donde se encuentre instalado el certificado al cual quieras acceder.

Comment: mmmmm creo que esa respuesta es apropiada para una pregunta tipo "¿Como accedo a los certificados digitales?", bueno eso no era mi consulta, pero bueno a ver seguiré investigando por mi parte y también esperando a ver si por aqui consigo colaboración de alguien